# Qual a diferença entre NULL e nullptr em C++

Tags: c++, ponteiro, struct, lista-encadeada

Eu gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre NULL e nullptr em C++, pois alguns códigos onde se é utilizado o nullptr e vi, que em algumas situações posso o utilizar, mas nesse caso, em uma Lista, Fila ou Pilha estruturada (sem o uso de bibliotecas, onde se tem já a estrutura pronta), queria saber, qual a principal diferença de um para o outro e também, quando devo utilizar um e quando usar o outro?